# Efficient retrieval of lat-lon points that are within a square boundary

Tags: database, react-native, algorithm, maps

I have a react-native application that populates pins on a map that have been submitted by users. The front end gets the corners of the window and then the back end goes through each pin to check if it falls within the boundary, and returns the ones that do.

This is taking too long on the backend and I want to ask the community for ideas, because I doubt I have the best one.

My idea is to store tables of pins grouped by quadrants, effectively a cache, and then I can in almost constant time return the pins from the quadrants involved.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Maybe using NoSQL?

Answer (score 0):

A month later it seems geohashing is probably the best way, plus AWS has a library for automatically handling this with dynamodb. Apparently it takes the corners of the screen, lat/lon, and automatically returns the items from the DB in the view, in, I assume, constant time, since that's the whole point of geohashing, getting performance that works at scale..

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-geo
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-geohashing-at-scale-in-serverless-web-applications/

Otherwise, using a geohashing library that is built for serving mobile apps likely exists.